# How to fetch data from SendLocationEvent in background locator

Tags: android, flutter, background, geolocation, android-gps

I am building application which needs to track user trajectories to detect if user has a pattern .

I am using flutter and Carp background location which is built around another package that is called background locator .

background locator tracks user even when app is closed or terminated by making the service a foreground service .
when the app is running I am able to fetch the data it sends and save it in sqf lite table ,
but when the app is terminated the carp foreground service keeps on running and printing SendLocationEvent to the terminal
but I can't fetch the data .
I tried using background fetch package but its not what I need.
is there a way I can put the sqflite insertion code in the Carp foreground tracking service ?

Answer (score -1):

it´s a problem with the library, you need to parse the `locationstream.listen(onData)`
toJson, because the name SendLocationEvent is an object but is not correct, you need something like that, `LocationDto.fromJson(dto.toJson);`